# Help with a regex that matches something either before OR after something else

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of XML that has lines that look like this

```
<_char font_name="/ITC Stone Serif Std Bold" italic="true" />
```

but sometimes look like this

```
<_char font_size="88175" italic="true" font_name="/ITC Stone Serif Std Bold" />
```

Here's what I need to do

- Replace **italic="true"** with **italic="false** for every line that contains **ITC Stone Serif Std Bold**, regardless of whether it comes before OR after the **italic** part.

Can this be done with a single regex?

I'm not looking for a real-time solution.  I just have a ton of XML files that have this "mistake" in them and I'm trying to do a global search-and-replace with PowerGrep which would require a single regex.  If scripting's the only way to do it, then so be it.

Comment: Why are you limited to a single regex?  It seems an easier way to do this is with two regexes, one for each case.

Comment: A single regex would be nice because of the way PowerGrep works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the simple use of '|' operator satisfy you ?

```
name="/ITC Stone Sans Std Bold"[^>]italic="(true)"|italic="(true)"[^>]font_name="/ITC Stone Serif Std Bold"
```

That should detect any line with the attribute name before of after attribute italic with value true.

Comment: That's probably the easiest way to do it.  I was mostly wondering if there was some magical regex operator I didn't know about.

Comment: Not to my knowledge... but may be a regexp guru can post a better solution.

Comment: This seems like the best approach for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general, using RE for XML parsing isn't a great idea.  But if you really wanted, the easiest way would be to just do it in two lines:

```
if (/ITC Stone Serif Std Bold/) {
   s/italic="true"/italic="false"/g;
}
```

Comment: 3 lines?  And that could match other font changes (something my solution also suffers from).

Answer (score 0):

In Perl - untested:

```
while (<>)
{
    s/italic="true"/italic="false"/ if m%font_name="/ITC Stone Sans Std Bold" italic="true"|italic="true" font_name="/ITC Stone Serif Std Bold"%;
    print;
}
```

Very simple minded - might need a global qualifier, might need a more complex substitute if other parts of the same line could contain italic options.

Also - a thought - should you take this opportunity to make the notation uniform, so always put italic in front of (or behind) the font name?

Comment: These are, unfortunately, auto-generated files.  Otherwise I'd be all in favor of standardizing.  Luckily I only have to do this once.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern: /(<_char(?=(?:\s+\w+="[^"]*")*?\s+font_name="[^"]*?ITC Stone Serif Std Bold[^"]*")(?:\s+\w+="[^"]*")*?\s+italic=")true(?=")/
Replacement: '$1false'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Perl 5.10

Using new features of Perl 5.10.

```
s(
 <_char \s* [^>]*? \K (?: (?&font) \s+ (?&italic) | (?&italic) \s+ (?&font) )
 (?(DEFINE)
  (?<font>font_name="/ITC[ ]Stone[ ]Serif[ ]Std[ ]Bold")
  (?<italic>italic="true")
 )
){
 $+{font} . 'italic="false"'
}xge
```

*Warning: not tested.*